# Android activity lifecycle and jni memory management

Tags: android, memory, java-native-interface

I am trying to make an android application, which uses some jni code.
This jni code allocates some memory, which has to be freed. Let`s
suppose I have this class containing this code:

```
class MyJniClass{

public native void jni_init(); //this allocates some memory
public native void do_something(); //this also allocates some memory,  
which is linked to the memory allocated in jni_init()
public native void jni_destroy(); //this frees all the allocated  
memory in two previous functions

... // some other java code

}
```

My trouble is, where in activity lifecycle to call `jni_init` and `jni_destroy`. So I started some digging how exactly the activity lifecycle works and I am a little bit confused about the results. I suppose that this is caused by the fact, that I am trying to
understand quite deeply to the level of linux processes. But I am using jni, so it makes some sense.

I created a simple activity, implemented all the lifecycle callbacks and put some logging into them. I did the same with the constructor and I also added jni code, which logs the `pid` of the process.

So, what I found
 - the activity can be destroyed even if onDestroy is not called (this is clear, I found lots of explanations for this) and the process is still runnig (verified by apps like Usage Timelines, ps command and the getpid jni call). The process is running, so it seems logical to keep the memory allocated.

The problem is, where to allocate the memory. I cannnot use `onCreate`, because it can called several times during the process lifetime, so memory leaks can happen. I also don't want to use onStart for allocation and onStop for freeing, because it unnecessary work to do. I tried the singleton design, it seems to work, but I don't want to use it, because I need MyJniClass to be reentrant (I want to use it also in a service). So my question is - is there some recommended way how to do memory management in jni apps?

Edit:
I see I didn`t describe the most confusing part of this clearly enough. Here is the sequens of events:

1) I start the app using the icon in launcher

2) new activity is created (constructed)

3) onCreate is called

4) onStart is called

5) onResume is called

6) I press the home button

7) onSaveInstanceState is called

8) onPause is called

9) onStop is called

10) I start the app using the icon in launcher (as in step 1)

11) new activity is created (constructed)

12) onCreate is called

13) onStart is called

14) onResume is called

The confusing steps are 11) and 12) because the process (pid) is still the same, but as I understand from documentation, the previous process should be killed if 11) and 12) happen.

Thanks and sorry for all the grammar mistakes.

Comment: "the previous process should be killed if 11) and 12) happen." -> And this doesn't happen ?
One more test you can do, check when the static constructor of your class is called (any `static { /* code here */ }` block at class level).

Comment: No, it doesn`t, the pid is still the same. I also added a simple static counter into the activity class, which is incremented everytime onCreate is called and it increasing. The code in static constructor is called only once (when te process is started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#finish)

> android:finishOnTaskLaunch
>
> Whether or not an existing instance of the activity should be shut down (finished) >whenever the user again launches its task (chooses the task on the home screen) — "true" if >it should be shut down, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".

It clearly states that you should change this value in AndroidManifest.xml if you want your activity to exist only once.

There are also other value you can change which will impact the activity life cycle behavior.

Comment: Thanks. It partialy helps. The problem is, that this only works if the activity is started from the icon, not by intent from another application. But it may be enough. Another thing is that the process is still allive, but I suppose I can`t control this. I also tryed android:launchMode="singleTop", it seems to be even better, but will work only if I have only one activity in my app. I`m marking this solved.

Comment: If you ever find a better solution, let me know !